# manipulate raw binary image data with python

Tags: python, image, image-processing, python-imaging-library, rgb

I have an raw binary image stored as a .bin file and it has some important data on it.  The problem is that the color information is slightly off so I need to alter it a little bit.  Is there any way I can get in and multiply the R, G, and B values by a scalar and then save it back as a raw binary file?

I am hoping to use the python imaging library to do this as I already know the basics of the image module.  I need to multiply every pixel by the same value but it will be a different value for R, G, and B.  I have the following code to open the file but then I don't know what to do there to alter the RGB values.

```
fileName = raw_input("Enter a file name: ")

with open(fileName) as f:
    im = Image.fromstring('RGB', (3032, 2016), f.read())
```

Let me know if you need any more information.

**UPDATE**:

I wrote the following code which is converting the image in a way that I would like but it gives me an error.  The code is as follows:

```
with open(C:\Users\name\imagedata\visiblespec.bin, 'rb') as f:
    im = Image.fromstring('RGB', (3032, 2016), f.read())

im = im.convert('RGB')
r, g, b = im.split()
r = r.point(lambda i: i * (255/171))
g = g.point(lambda i: i * (255/107))
b = b.point(lambda i: i * (255/157))
out = Image.merge('RGB', (r, g, b))


out.save(C:\Users\name\imagedata\visiblespecredone.bin)
```

and my error is this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Patrick\workspace\colorCorrect\src\rawImage.py", line 18, in <module>
    im = Image.fromstring('RGB', (3032, 2016), f.read()) 
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 1797, in fromstring
    im.fromstring(data, decoder_name, args)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 594, in fromstring
    raise ValueError("not enough image data")
ValueError: not enough image data
```

This may be a completely wrong way to edit the RGB values, I know it works for a JPEG and t may only work for a JPEG but this is what I would like to do.

Comment: Could you elaborate on the format of your raw binary file?

Comment: 16 bit unsigned integers around 11 mbs and written in hexadecimal

Comment: It would appear to be that your file size is either not (or not being read as) a correct multiple of RGB values. Try `.frombuffer` method and check the size is what you expect?

Comment: For binary data: 3032 x 2016 = 6,112,512 pixels x 3 bytes per pixel (RGB) = 18,337,536 bytes = 17.488 MB, so 11 MB sounds too small (as in not enough image data).

Comment: Indeed is does sound like a 15 or 16 bit RGB format. Unfortunately the only raw modes that PIL v1.1.7 handles (as defined in the unpack.c file) are BGR;15 or BGR;16 which it will converted to RGB888.

Comment: @clifgray: What _exactly_ is the layout of RGB bits per pixel in the image?

Comment: So it actually is a 16 bit unsigned integer grayscale photo that I am converting to RGB with a bayer filter... that may be the problem, I'll update in a second

Comment: @clifgray: Yes that's your problem. Your telling PIL it's an RGB image you're trying to read in.

Answer (score 2):

```
import numpy as np

shape = (2016, 3032)
im = np.fromfile('visiblespec.bin', 'uint16').reshape(shape)

def tile(pattern, shape):
    return np.tile(np.array(pattern, 'bool'), (shape[0] // 2, shape[1] // 2))

r = tile([[0, 0], [0, 1]], shape)
g = tile([[0, 1], [1, 0]], shape)
b = tile([[1, 0], [0, 0]], shape)

im = im.astype('float32')
im[r] *= 255 / 171.
im[g] *= 255 / 107.
im[b] *= 255 / 157.
np.rint(im, out=im)
np.clip(im, 0, 65535, out=im)
im = im.astype('uint16')

im.tofile('visiblespecredone.bin')
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look at [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php) with the Python bindings or [PIL](http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/).

If you just need to *read the file* and manipulate the binary data, do something like:

```
with open(filename, 'rb') as img:
   wrd=img.read(2)
   while wrd:
       # wrd == 2 bytes == your 16 bits...
```

Comment: yeah I'm using PIL right now but can't quite figure out how to edit specific values with it but I'm going through the documentation again

Comment: Doing it this way would be very slow if done in pure Python for an image of this size.

Comment: @martineau: maybe, but the underlying OS will buffer this more than most give credit for.

Comment: @drewk: Buffering isn't going to eliminate the bit manipulations and scaling of three component values needed per pixel -- not to mention those likely necessary to write the image back out (in its original format).

Comment: @martineau: Agreed. It is not an ideal solution, but bit-by-bit with PIL is not going to be a speed demon either. It sounds like he has an image size error in any case, and this does not really apply.

Comment: @drewk: PIL has many low-level routines written in C including applying scaling transformation to whole images. The problem is I don't think it has a built-in decoder for RGB565 (assuming that there's the proper amount of data in the file, which does seem to be the case -- see cgohlke's comment attached to the question).